# How to put activity from your site in facebook user's profile

Tags: facebook, android-activity, yahoo

When I log in with Facebook at http://news.yahoo.com/ and I visit some article, a link to this article is shown at my facebook wall.

The note on Facebook says, for example "Paul read article *Pannetta Formally Shuts Down US War in Iraq* in application *Yahoo!*"

I would like to add same feature to my website. How to do it? I could't find any usefull examples or tutorials.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has a [Step-by-Step Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial) that covers this capability. I recommend starting with the documentation on Actions and Objects before delving into the tutorial if you have no experience with Graph API.